# Clarification on question: A bipartite graph has a unique bipartition (up to changing two sets) iff it is connected

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory, proof-writing, definition

I need a clarification on the question: *a bipartite graph has a unique bipartition (up to changing two sets) iff it is connected*

Specifically, I am not sure what it means by "unique bipartition".

Consider the following graph

[image]

The graph is disconnected since there isn't a path connecting the first bottom vertex to the second top vertex, but why isn't the bipartition (shown by the encircled)

[image]

unique?
Graph created using: https://www.draw.io/

**Note: Ok I figured out the answer by the time I wrote this question, but feel free to provide answer to the benefit of other readers.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bipartition can be formed by doing a proper 2-colouring of the vertices. If the graph is connected, up to colour choice there is only one such colouring. If the graph is disconnected with $n$ components, each component can have one of two colourings, leading to $2^{n-1}$ bipartitions up to swapping the two parts.

In the given example, a different bipartition can be formed by letting one part have the northwest and southeast vertices, the other taking the northeast and southwest vertices.